# don't replace some occurrences using str_replace

Tags: php

I have a string like this "{text}...{text}...{text}...text..." I need to replace the "text" value in the string but only the ones that are not in curly or square brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should then use regular expressions :

```
/(?<!({|\[))text(?!(}|\]]))/
```

You can use this with [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) :

```
preg_replace("/(?<!({|\[))text(?!(}|\]]))/", $replace, $string);
```

Comment: thanks but it only works on {} not [] :) i would really be greatful if you help me with it. i suck at regular expressions

Comment: [ and ] need to be escaped when you want to match against them in a regular expression: \\[ and \\]